# How to move elements along with svg group

Tags: d3.js

I have a circle that gets appended on drag drop. I want the circle to move along with group when I move the group around with mouse

Here's what I have tried which isn't working:

```
//targetG is the group element

targetG.append("rect")
                        .attr("fill", "none")
                        .style("stroke", "black")
                        .style("stroke-width", "2px")
                        .attr("width", 200)
                        .attr("height", 200)
                        .style("fill", "white")
                        .call(
                                d3.behavior.drag()
                                .on('drag', moveRect).origin(function () {
                            var t = d3.select(this);
                            return {x: t.attr("x"), y: t.attr("y")};
                        }));
```

Here's the full code in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vk62y7un/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a couple of small problems that need to be fixed.

---

Your translate component split function is splitting by ,.

> translate = (translate.substring(0, translate.indexOf(")"))).split(",");

While this works in Chrome, it should be splitting by space for IE.

```
translate = (translate.substring(0, translate.indexOf(")"))).split(",");
if (translate.length === 1)
    translate = translate[0].split(' ');
```

The circle wasn't being attached to the g because of this.

---

Your (container) drag event is attached to the rectangle inside the g. This should be attached to the g instead. Correspondingly the drag functions should manipulate the transform (translate) attribute and not the x and y.

```
var targetG = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(150,150)")
        .call(
        d3.behavior.drag()
        .on('drag', moveRect).origin(function () {
        ...
```

and

```
function moveRect() {
    d3.select(this)
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + d3.event.x + ' ' + d3.event.y +')');
}
```

---

The origin (for the g now) should be the (parsed) transform (translate) attribute at the start of the drag.

```
        ....
        var tc = d3.select(this).attr('transform').replace(/[a-z()]/g, '').split(' ');
        if (tc.length === 1)
            tc = tc[0].split(',')
        return { x: Number(tc[0]), y: Number(tc[1]) };
    }));
```

Notice, the ===1 check and split - that's so that it works in IE and Chrome.

---

Fiddle (works in IE and Chrome) - http://jsfiddle.net/3hyu6om8/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you try to drag rectangle you don't select circles. I made some changes and you could drag circles along rectangle.

Add this part to your code:

```
var groupAll = d3.behavior.drag()
        .origin(Object)
        .on("drag", function(d, i) {
        var child = this;
        var move = d3.transform(child.getAttribute("transform")).translate;
        var x = d3.event.dx + move[0];
        var y = d3.event.dy + move[1];
        d3.select(child).attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y +   ")");

        });
```

Complete Code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/YrRpU3gCBTWSvrSlXdQu?p=preview).